# Django ON_DELETE policy not being applied in DB

Tags: django, postgresql

I have the following model:

```py
class GeneMiRNACombination(models.Model):
    gene = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    experiment = models.ForeignKey(Experiment, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    source_statistical_data = models.OneToOneField(
        SourceDataStatisticalProperties,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        default=None
    )
```

So I'd expect tha the `ON_DELETE` will be setted in the DB (Postgres in my case). But when I see the CREATE script this is what it prints:

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.gene_mirna_combination
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('gene_mirna_combination_id_seq'::regclass),
    gene character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    experiment_id integer NOT NULL,
    source_statistical_data_id integer,
    CONSTRAINT gene_mirna_combination_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT gene_mirna_combination_properties_id_key UNIQUE (source_statistical_data_id),
    CONSTRAINT gene_mirna_combinati_experiment_id_31b52a17_fk_api_servi FOREIGN KEY (experiment_id)
        REFERENCES public.api_service_experiment (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
    CONSTRAINT gene_mirna_combinati_source_statistical_d_7d0f04a8_fk_statistic FOREIGN KEY (source_statistical_data_id)
        REFERENCES public.statistical_properties_sourcedatastatisticalproperties (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.gene_mirna_combination
    OWNER to root;

CREATE INDEX gene_mirna_combination_experiment_id_31b52a17
    ON public.gene_mirna_combination USING btree
    (experiment_id ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

So, there is no action on delete! Why? It should set the `ON DELETE CASCADE` when creates the table, shouldn't it? Is there any implicit behaviour?

If there isn't an ON DELETE policy so every time I remove a referenced object it must be removed from Django, which will be extremely slower than a SQL robust solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django does not apply constraints to the the DB schema; same for server defaults for instance.

To be really honest I hate this behaviour but .... Django works in that way and we have to leave with it

**UPDATE**

You can follow the discussion about this [PR](https://github.com/django/django/pull/8661) and the related [feature request](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21961)

Comment: Cool! Thak you so much and sorry for the delay. Could you add [this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21961) and [this PR](https://github.com/django/django/pull/8661) to your answer to have some official references, please?